# Checkbox not returning the right value jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to get the value (true or false) of a checkbox and update the database of a row in a while function. However, the checkboxes only seem to register a change of value depending on the first row. For example, if row 1 checkbox is checked, value = true. I can then click on the following rows and get checkbox value of true. However, when I click rows beyond the first row to get false, it will only register if the first row checkbox was unchecked first. I think it's something to do with the row id but tried for ages to fixed this but can't fix it. Please help.

HTML/PHP

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo
'
<input type="checkbox" name="home['.$row["id"].']" id="'.$row["id"].'" '.($row["home"]>0 ? 'checked="checked"' : '').'>
            <label for="'. $row["id"].'"></label>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function(){
        var on = $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked");
        $.post("work/updateaddress.php",{home:on,id:this.id});
            });
        });
```

PHP/MYSQL

```
  if ($home == 'true') {
  $check = date("Ymd");
} else {
  $check = '';
}
if(isset($_POST["home"])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET home='$check' WHERE id='$id'";
  if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE){
         } else {
      echo "error" . $sql . "<br>".$mysqli->error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the checkboxes in the click handler and then accessing `prop()` on that collection, which will only return the value from the first one.

Instead, use the `this` keyword to reference the checkbox which raised the event. You should also use the `change` event instead of `click` for accessibility reasons:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  var on = $(this).prop("checked"); // or just this.checked
  $.post("work/updateaddress.php", {
    home: on,
    id: this.id
  });
});
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped - on some of your previous questions too.

Answer (score 0):

//Use `this` to refer to the box being clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function(){
        var on = $(this).prop("checked");
        $.post("work/updateaddress.php",{home:on,id:this.id});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `change` event instead of `click` event for the checkbox.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  var on = this.checked
  console.log(on)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="a">
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to change you could use `input`

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('input', function(e){
  let thisCheckbox = e.target.checked
  alert(thisCheckbox)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="row1" id="row1" checked="checked">
            <label for="row1">row1</label>
```